# fabric-ca-server command not found

Tags: linux, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html#initializing-the-server

I tried
`fabric-ca-server init -b myID:myPW`

but error occurred
`fabric-ca-server command not found`

I want to know

1. how to set FABRIC_CA_SERVER_HOME variable
2. where I have to try `fabric-ca-server init -b myID:myPW` in what directory?

linux server is 18.04

go 1.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set HOME path of server:

> ```
> export FABRIC_CA_SERVER_HOME=${HOME}/fabric-ca/server
> ```

2. The client and server should have been installed in $GOPATH/bin. You can set your $PATH so that the server can be run from any directory.

> ```
> cd ${GOPATH}/bin
> fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw
> ```

Answer (score 0):

**Install Fabric and Fabric Samples**

You need to follow those steps

```
mkdir -p $HOME/go/src/github.com/<your_github_userid>
cd $HOME/go/src/github.com/<your_github_userid>

./install-fabric.sh d s b
```

add `export PATH=$PATH:/home/$USER/go/src/github.com/TanjinAlam/fabric-samples/bin` on your `sudo nano /.bashrc` file

check it worked or not

```
which fabric-ca-client
fabric-ca-client version
```